# Float left not working as it should

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to make some divs float left to create some drop down menu. My problem is this. When I do float left, unless the div after the first one also has float: left, it will go inside the first div.

I can't put float: left, on everything because it means I can't really do anything. It was working before, but I'm not sure why they're going in inside each other?

```css
#box1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}
#box2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
</div>
<div id="box2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

MaKe both the divs float left

```
  #box1{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    }
    #box2{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
float:left
    }
```

Div is itself a block element, to make it inline use float on both divs

Comment: Still won't work seeing as the next element will then go inside them, which I don't want.

Comment: if you are using bootstrap then add a div with class clearfix after end div it will make other elements in next line. if not then use div  and set css property clear:both;

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work just fine with the input suggested by Asif Ahmed.

Just add `float: left;` at #box2

(added margin to show its not overlapping)

https://jsfiddle.net/jwe5cohy/

Comment: Like I said, if I have float: left  on the SECOND div, something after that will go /into/ the divs. 

Copy your code, but add another div without float: left, it will go INTO the two divs.

Adding float: left isn't gonna work when I need to make a website. What am I going to do? add float: left to every single element??

Comment: Im not sure if I understood you, but you could add another div surrounding the two others. 

https://jsfiddle.net/Blomkfist174/jwe5cohy/1/

Is that what you mean?